# How would I make a <div> automatically make a new line judged on the input?

Tags: html, css

What I mean is, is it possible to make a div that when you type stuff into a div, it automatically makes a new line for each new line in the code it detects? For example, I want this:

```
<div>
    Hello, World!
    How are you doing today?
</div>
```

which would return

> Hello, World!
>   How are you doing today?

Which in reality requires a `<br>` or something. I don't want to have to put millions of them to make simple lines. The code I put before really outputs this:

> Hello, World! How are you doing today?

I want automatic new line judged on the code's enters. Is this possible?

Comment: What is your end goal? Are you hoping to do this once with a large text field or are you wanting to use this technique frequently?

Comment: I am making a personal website centered on programming, and I want to make working code boxes. http://prntscr.com/5dplrd That's what I'm going for, but with proper enters. I want to be able to paste in code that I don't have to individually put <br>'s and stuff.

Comment: Use the `<pre>` tag.

Comment: There is probably an HTML character code for enter key.

Comment: It's possible (as many of the answers here show), but it may be better to just do things the "correct" way in the long run. The content inside of the div should also probably be wrapped in <P> tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [CSS white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) property.

```
<div style="white-space:pre">
    Hello, World!
    How are you doing today?
</div>
```

Note that this will preserve all white space, including multiple spaces (such as your indent). If you want to collapse white space but still use newline characters to indicate line breaking, you can use the `pre-line` value, though this option is not supported in ie7 (if that matters to you).

See a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/vyme6xs8/1/

Comment: That is definitely the correct CSS. However, @zanfran, note that [you should not use the `style` attribute](http://phrogz.net/CSS/HowToDevelopWithCSS.html#separatestyle) to apply this to the div in question.

Comment: @Phrogz - For scalable applications you are absolutely correct. However, for short demonstrations of a CSS attribute, such nit-picking comes across as very pedantic.

Comment: I know. It is in my CSS, and I use it well. Thanks, again!